# What is a Kubernetes LoadBalancer On-Prem

Tags: kubernetes

I understand that, in Cloud scenarios, a LoadBalancer resource refers to and provisions an external layer 4 load balancer. There is some proprietary integration by which the cluster configures this load balancing. OK.

On-prem we have no such integration so we create our own load balancer outside of the cluster which distributes traffic to all nodes - effectively, in our case to the ingress.

I see no need for the cluster to know anything about this external load balancer.

What is a LoadBalancer* then in an on-prem scenario? Why do I have them? Why do I need one? What does it do? What happens when I create one? What role does the LoadBalancer resource play in ingress traffic. What effect does the LoadBalancer have outside the cluster? Is a LoadBalancer just a way to get a new IP address? How/why/ where does the IP point to and where does the IP come from?

- All questions refer to the Service of type “LoadBalancer” inside cluster and not my load balancer outside the cluster of which the cluster has no knowledge.

Comment: nothing will happen, your service will show always pending in the external ip adress field.

Comment: And your last point doesnt make sense because there is no loadbalancer inside the cluster. Service of type loadbalancer refers to the fact that a loadbalancer from outside points to the service's nodeport(s), more or less.

Comment: I agree there is no *load balancer* inside the cluster. I am asking about the *LoadBalancer* Resource inside Kubernetes. What is it, what does it do etc…

Comment: I dont know what you mean by loadbalancer resource. Can you please share a link to the docs referencing this?

Comment: I mean a Service of `type: LoadBalancer`

Comment: I have adressed that in the first 2 comments. It does nothing on prem. Your service will have its external ip pending forever. It does in the cloud what you have described you are doing on prem manually, point an external loadbalancer at your service, i.e. your ingress controller.

Comment: I asked many questions- which questions are your comments addressing?

Comment: I have an on-prem cluster and the external IPs are not pending. I did not set the IPs. Using k3s.

Comment: I am saying that if you create a service with type loadbalancer on prem, nothing will happen. There is nothing in the background that creates this loadbalancer for you. Hence its exernal ip will be pending.

Comment: there are some extra tools that can make it work, but by default nothing happens.

Comment: OK so basically any software which monitors my cluster for unassigned LB services and then gets an IP and publishes the IP (e.g. using ARP) assigning it to my nodes has achieved true load balancing?

Comment: basically yes, I never did something like this. I just know it exists. Here someone wrote an article about it https://itnext.io/kubernetes-service-type-lb-for-on-prem-deployments-89e9b2a73a0c

Comment: metallb can do that, see my answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments a kubernetes service of type LoadBalancer can not be used by default with on-prem setups. You can use [metallb](https://metallb.universe.tf/) to setup a service of that type in an on prem environment.

> Kubernetes does not offer an implementation of network load balancers (Services of type LoadBalancer) for bare-metal clusters. [...] If you’re not running on a supported IaaS platform (GCP, AWS, Azure…), LoadBalancers will remain in the “pending” state indefinitely when created. [...] MetalLB aims to redress this imbalance by offering a network load balancer implementation that integrates with standard network equipment, so that external services on bare-metal clusters also “just work” as much as possible.

You can for example use the BGP mode to advertise the service's IP to your router, read more on that in the [docs](https://metallb.universe.tf/concepts/bgp/).

The project is still in beta but is promoted as production ready and used by several bigger companies.

**Edit**

Regarding your question in the comments:

> Can I just broadcast the MAC address of my node and manually add the IP I am broadcasting to the LoadBalancer service via kubectl edit?

Yes that would work too. That's basically what metallb does, announcing the IP and updating the service.

Why need a software then? Imaging having 500 hosts that come and go with thousends of services of type `LoadBalancer` that come and go. You need an automation here.

> Why does Kubernetes need to know this IP?

It doesn't. If you don't use an external ip, the service is still usable via it's NodePort, see for example the [istio docs](https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/traffic-management/ingress/ingress-control/#determining-the-ingress-ip-and-ports) (with a little more details added by me):

```
$ kubectl get svc istio-ingressgateway -n istio-system
NAME                   TYPE           CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP      PORT(S)
istio-ingressgateway   LoadBalancer   192.12.129.119   <Pending>   [...],80:32123/TCP,443:30994/TCP,[...]
```

Here the external IP is not set and stays in `<Pending>`. You can still use the service by pointing your traffic to `<Node-IP>:32123` for plain http and to `<Node-IP>:30994` for https. As you can see above those ports are mapped to 80 and 443.

If the external ip is set you can direct traffic directly to port 80 and 443 on the external load balancer. Kube-Proxy will create an iptables chain with the destination of you external ip, that basically leads from the external IP over the service ip with a load balancer configuration to a pod ip.

To investigate that set up a service of type LoadBalancer, make sure it has an external ip, connect to the host and run the iptables-save command (e.g. `iptables-save | less`). Search for the external ip and follow the chain until you end up at the pod.

Comment: Can I just broadcast the MAC address of my node and manually add the IP I am broadcasting to the LoadBalancer service via kubectl edit? Why does Kubernetes need to know this IP??

Comment: I updated my answer to address those two questions.

Comment: You’ve provided a very good answer - thanks! So Ingress is possible without a Service of type LoadBalancer?

Comment: @Marc Yes, that's very much possible

Comment: @Chris I want contact you via email. Can you write https://christoph-raab.github.io/ in English. My email: donhuvy@hotmail.com , http://github.com/donhuvy . I like your cheat sheet so much, but I can not read it (not English).

Comment: Thanks mate. Sadly I currently don't have the time to translate the content or even curate the website. Good luck with the cka. I strongly recommand using killer.sh to simulate the exam.