# Configure Ingress traffic for Kubernetes image

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

I have a standalone Kubernetes cluster:

```
plane node - hostname kubernetes1 - 192.168.1.126
work node - hostname kubernetes2 - 192.168.1.138
```

I deployed this private repository:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: pv1
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 5Gi # specify your own size
  volumeMode: Filesystem
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Retain
  local:
    path: /opt/registry # can be any path
  nodeAffinity:
    required:
      nodeSelectorTerms:
      - matchExpressions:
        - key: kubernetes.io/hostname
          operator: In
          values:
          - kubernetes2
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany # only 1 node will read/write on the path.
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: pv1-claim
spec: # should match specs added in the PersistenVolume
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  volumeMode: Filesystem
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 5Gi
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: private-repository-k8s
  labels:
    app: private-repository-k8s
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: private-repository-k8s
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: private-repository-k8s
    spec:
      volumes:
       - name: certs-vol
         hostPath:
          path: /opt/certs
          type: Directory
       - name: task-pv-storage
         persistentVolumeClaim:
           claimName: pv1-claim # specify the PVC that you've created. PVC and Deployment must be in same namespace.
      containers:
        - image: registry:2
          name: private-repository-k8s
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          env:
          - name: REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_CERTIFICATE
            value: "/opt/certs/registry.crt"
          - name: REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_KEY
            value: "/opt/certs/registry.key"
          ports:
            - containerPort: 5000
          volumeMounts:
          - name: certs-vol
            mountPath: /opt/certs
          - name: task-pv-storage
            mountPath: /opt/registry
```

Service is deployed on the work node:

```
kubernetes@kubernetes1:/opt/registry$ kubectl get pods
NAME                                      READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
private-repository-k8s-6d5d954b4f-ldwd6   1/1     Running   0          153m
kubernetes@kubernetes1:/opt/registry$
```

I tried to create a ingress access because I want to access this pod from the outside:

```
kubectl create namespace test
```

***service controller:***

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1   
kind: Ingress   
metadata:
  namespace: test   
  name: private-repository-service-ingress   
  annotations:   
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1   
spec:   
  rules:   
    - host: kubernetes2   
      http:   
        paths:   
          - path: /   
            pathType: Prefix   
            backend:   
              service:   
                name: private-repository-service   
                port:   
                  number: 5000
```

***service-load-balancer:***

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  namespace: test
  name: private-repository-service
spec:
  #type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: private-repository-k8s
  ports:
      # By default and for convenience, the `targetPort` is set to the same value as the `port` field.
    - port: 5000
      targetPort: 5000
      # Optional field
      # By default and for convenience, the Kubernetes control plane will allocate a port from a range (default: 30000-32767)
      #nodePort: 30007
```

When I run `curl 192.168.1.138:5000` there is no response.
Do you know where I might be wrong?

***EDIT:***

```
kubernetes@kubernetes1:~$ kubectl get svc
NAME                       TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)    AGE
kubernetes                 ClusterIP   10.96.0.1        <none>        443/TCP    3d20h
private-registry-service   ClusterIP   10.103.148.234   <none>        5000/TCP   6h34m
kubernetes@kubernetes1:~$
```

Comment: Can you do a `kubectl get svc` and share the response ?

Comment: Is this fixed or still facing issues?

Comment: I still haven't fixed it. I still have connect timeout.

Comment: Ah ingress controller was the issue I too had similar issue now I have got proper understanding about ingress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you don't have an ingress-controller of any kind and just want to access the registry directly. In that case you need to create a service of type `NodePort`.

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  namespace: test
  name: private-repository-service
spec:
  type: NodePort # Added
  selector:
    app: private-repository-k8s
  ports:
    - port: 5000
      targetPort: 5000
      nodePort: 30123 # Added
```

This will bind the service port 5000 to the host's port 30123.
If you run `kubectl get svc` this will than give you a slightly different output.

```bash
kubernetes@kubernetes1:~$ kubectl get svc
NAME                       TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)    AGE
kubernetes                 ClusterIP   10.96.0.1        <none>        443/TCP    3d20h
private-registry-service   ClusterIP   10.103.148.234   <none>        5000:30123/TCP   6h34m
```

Notice the mapping `30312:5000`. Now you can send a request to the registry on that port: `curl 192.168.1.138:30312`. You can also omit the `nodePort` field, kubernetes will then choose a random one in the range between 3000 and 32767 for you. It will be displayed in the `kubectl get svc` command as shown above. The `Ingress` is not needed and can be removed.

If you want to use an `Ingress` as you provided you need to use an ingress-controller, like nginx or traefik, see also [kubernetes docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/) on that topic.

> [...] An Ingress controller is responsible for fulfilling the Ingress, usually with a load balancer, though it may also configure your edge router or additional frontends to help handle the traffic.

**EDIT**

There are a lot of ingress-controllers out there, they all have their advantages and disadvantages. For a beginner, nginx might be a good choise, see [docs](https://docs.nginx.com/).

To install it, run these commands (from the [install docs page](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx-ingress-controller/installation/installation-with-helm/))

```bash
$ helm repo add nginx-stable https://helm.nginx.com/stable
$ helm repo update
$ helm install my-release nginx-stable/nginx-ingress
```

where `my-release` is a random name, you can choose what ever you want. This will create an nginx pod in the namespace you installed the chart. It will also create an nginx-ingress service of type `LoadBalancer`, like this:

```
kubectl get svc
NAME                       TYPE           CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP          
my-release-nginx-ingress   LoadBalancer   10.109.27.49   <pending>     80:30536/TCP,443:31694/TCP   111s
```

As you can see the `EXTERNAL-IP` is in `<pending>` state. In a public cloud environment like AWS a load-balancer resource like ELB is created and its public ip will be assigned to the service as `EXTERNAL-IP`. In your on-premise setup it will stay in `<pending>` status. But as you can see, two random node ports are mapped to the http/https ports, like with the `nodePort` setup above. Here it's 80 -> 30536 and 433 -> 31694, for you it will be something similar.

Now you can apply your manifests as above. You'll get a service of type `ClusterIP`. Also create an `Ingress` like this:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: private-repository-service 
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
    - host: example.com
      http:
        paths:
        - path: /
          pathType: Prefix
          backend:
            service:
              name: private-repository-service 
              port:
                number: 5000
```

Now you can run curl against that host `curl -HHost:example.com "http://192.168.1.138:30536/"` (for me it's port 30536, will be a different one for you) and you will get an answer from the registry. Works the same with https using the other port.

Note that I installed everything in the same namespace. In reality you should have a dedicated ingress namespace.

I would also highly recommand to learn the basics of kubernetes, e.g. by a Udemy Course or a youtube tutorail series. If you want to know more about ingress-controller in an on-premise setup, check out my other [answer on that topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71747959/what-is-a-kubernetes-loadbalancer-on-prem/71753345#71753345).

Comment: Thanks, I have one more request. Can you show me how this can be configured with ingress controller and all the configuration to be applied a HELM charts?

Comment: What do you mean by "all the configuration to be applied a HELM charts"? You want to install an ingress-controller with helm and use it with an `Ingress` object to route traffic to your registry?

Comment: hm.... I'm new to Kubernetes. The general idea is to create everything with HELM charts. I think that I need  ingress-controller with helm and use it with an Ingress object to route traffic to the registry?

Comment: Can you advice, is this setup possible?

Comment: Sure, I updated my answer. Please consider accepting it and assign the bounty if it would helpful. I tested the setup my local kubernetes to make sure it works.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please make this change in the ingress.yaml and then apply this ingress.Also please post the output of `kubectl get ingress`

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-private-registry-service
  annotations:
    # use the shared ingress-nginx
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
spec:
  rules:
  - host: kubernetes2
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: private-registry-service
            port:
              number: 5000
```

Comment: I get `Error from server (NotFound): error when deleting "ingress-resource-new.yaml": ingresses.networking.k8s.io "ingress-private-registry-service" not found`

Comment: can you show me your manifest ? why do you have service name as ingress-private-registry-service ? backend block has a name and it must be same name as your service which is deployed

Comment: hm..... it's the same as the one into the post description. I tried to apply the one from your post.

Comment: did u change the service name ? I could see from your question that it is private-registry-service. Just do `kubectl get svc` and see if svc name has been changed

Comment: no, it's the same.

Comment: Can you show the output of ‘kubectl get ingress

Comment: I get `No resources found in default namespace.`

Comment: Let's make a call so that I can show you exact steps?

Comment: email me the invite

Comment: I don't have your e-mail

Comment: I had shared with you yesterday ? You had sent me the documents as well

Comment: oh, yeah. I forgot. mail is send

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your private repository is in the `default` namespace and you are creating the `Service` and `Ingress` in the `test` namespace.

I recommend you to move all the resources to the same namespace. If for some reason this is not possible, then you would need to make use of the [Service Mesh](https://istio.io/latest/about/service-mesh/#what-is-a-service-mesh) paradigm, for which you can find several tools like [Istio](https://istio.io/latest/about/service-mesh/#what-is-istio), [Anthos](https://cloud.google.com/anthos/service-mesh), etc.

Comment: I had troubleshooted i too assumed this was the issue but its not i highly suspect that the registry deployment has some issue.